# What am I missing to apply this JQuery widget to dynamic elements?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have the following script:

```
$(function() {
   $( 'input[id^="event_"' ).each(function() {
        this.datetimepicker({
            stepMinute: 15  
        });
    }); 
});
```

Typically applying the `datetimepicker` widget involves this code (which is working further up on the page):

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datetimepicker({
        stepMinute: 15  
    });
});
```

What it should be doing is applying the `datetimepicker` widget to each of the input boxes in this generated code:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Event Name</td>
            <td>Event Date</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="1" value="Opening" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="event_1" value="2011-09-15 20:30:00" /></td>
            <td>Save stuff here?</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="2" value="First Act" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="event_2" value="2011-09-15 20:45:00" /></td>
            <td>Save stuff here?</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="3" value="Some Event" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="event_3" value="2011-09-16 20:00:00" /></td>
            <td>Save stuff here?</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="4" value="Some Other Event" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="event_4" value="2011-09-17 20:00:00" /></td>
            <td>Save stuff here?</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="30" value="1234" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="event_30" value="2011-09-30 11:00:00" /></td>
            <td>Save stuff here?</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="32" value="Statement Check" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="event_32" value="2011-09-29 10:30:00" /></td>
            <td>Save stuff here?</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am 95% sure that my syntax is wrong in the `$(function() { ... });` block, but I am not sure where I went wrong.

EDIT: As a side note, this will eventually edit the listed events via an AJAX call. So each row is an event that needs individual saving once edited.

Thank you all in advanced for all input/suggestions/solutions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `each` function, `this` refers to the native DOM node, which has no method by the name of `datetimepicker`. To use `datetimepicker`, you have to create a jQuery object out of it, by passing it to the jQuery constructor `$(this)`:

```
$(function() {
   $( 'input[id^="event_"]' ).each(function() {
        $(this).datetimepicker({
            stepMinute: 15  
        });
    }); 
});
```

---

However, you shouldn't need this at all. You can forgo `each` completely, and call the `datetimepicker` directly on the original collection:

```
$(function() {
   $( 'input[id^="event_"]' ).datetimepicker({
        stepMinute: 15  
   });
});
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried that first and it doesn't seem to be working. Am I applying that filter properly? Meaning, it should be saying "apply datepicker to each input field with an id that starts with 'event_'", correct?

Comment: You're missing the closing bracket. Try to log it: `console.log($('input[id^="event_"]'));`. What do you get?

Comment: Actually, I was missing the closing bracket for the selector. *Doh*. Works fine now. Thank you for the help!

Comment: The next step will be passing the date/time to the widget.